# Can organizations no longer be review authors to get Google stars rich snippets?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets, structured-data, user-reviews

I've noticed in the last few months after [Google restricted](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/09/making-review-rich-results-more-helpful.html) schema review stars in certain cases that another side effect seems to have happened:

If a review "author" is marked up as an Organization, the stars don't seem to appear, even if the schema data validates properly using the Structured Data Testing Tool.

However, in Google's own review guidelines, it says authors can be an Organization:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet

This scenario is also not mentioned anywhere in their public blog posts, social media discussions, or otherwise regarding the new limitations on schema stars.

Can anyone explain this peculiarity?

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, Google will not show stars from an organization unknown to it. That is, if an organization is not registered in Google My Business and does not have a knowledge panel in SERP, then Google can ignore such an organization as the author of a review. You will probably agree that this makes sense.

Comment: That is an interesting theory, however GMB is only for local businesses. I don't believe Google would ignore all non-local Organizations, etc.

Comment: Which business do you think is local? Each business must register the address of the business upon registration, which is then indicated in the registration certificate. Thus, any business takes place locally. In addition, Google My Business has an option such as work from home.